# While making a build of angular-6 application am getting this error how i can resolve this?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular6

```
**ng build --prod (error) how i can resolve this issue!**
```

F:\practice\ang-node\frontend> `ng build --prod`

> Date: 2018-08-28T04:08:06.648Z Hash: 61fab25db19a36ad55ca Time:
>   89374ms chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB
>   [entry] [rendered] chunk {1} styles.78fc82606a60ff243473.css (styles)
>   193 kB [initial] [rendered] chunk {2}
>   polyfills.7a0e6866a34e280f48e7.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {3} main.b6f6160fdfad736b2ba4.js (main) 1.18 MB
>   [initial] [rendered]
>
> ERROR in ./node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js Module build
>   failed: Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
>       at getJSDocTags (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13197:22)
>       at getFirstJSDocTag (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13205:24)
>       at Object.getJSDocTypeTag (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13154:19)
>       at checkParenthesizedExpression (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45628:56)
>       at checkExpressionWorker (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45676:28)
>       at checkExpression (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
>       at checkBinaryLikeExpression (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45155:29)
>       at checkBinaryExpression (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45147:20)
>       at checkExpressionWorker (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45702:28)
>       at checkExpression (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45609:42)
>       at checkExpressionCached (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45457:38)
>       at getTypeOfExpression (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45577:28)
>       at checkDeclarationInitializer (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:45469:24)
>       at getTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30738:28)
>       at getWidenedTypeForVariableLikeDeclaration (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:30961:24)
>       at getTypeOfVariableOrParameterOrProperty (F:\practice\ang-node\frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:31062:28)

F:\practice\ang-node\frontend>[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0M8c.png)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular2-jwt` is supposed to be used with Angular 2 only. For Angular 6 you will need to use `@auth0/angular-jwt` which supports RxJS v6+.